# How to improve performance and prevent "Timeout during reading attempt" of multiple table join query in C# Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We are currently working on a GET endpoint that retrieves data from multiple tables in PostgreSQL database using C# Entity Framework Core.

The data retrieval operation gives a timeout exception, and fails to retrieve the data. Each of the joined tables (having one-to-many relationships with the main table) contain around 10 records for each record of the main table. The following code starts working, retrieving data as expected once you delete and reduce data from the join tables (from 10 to around 2).

We would be grateful if you could help us know any approach that could improve the performance, and prevent this exception.

```
Timeout Exception Details:
Exception: NpgsqlException
Message: "Exception while reading from stream"
Inner Exception Message: "Timeout during reading attempt"
Stack Trace: 
"   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|42_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|234_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<Read>d__43.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at ..."
```

This is the code in the repository layer:

```cs
public async Task<ResultDataList<Hotel>> GetHotels(HotelFilterData hotelFilterData, int pageNumber, int pageSize, 
                                                    string sortField, string sortOrder)
{
    var query = _dbContext.Hotels.AsQueryable();

    if (hotelFilterData.BrandId != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(h => h.BrandId == hotelFilterData.BrandId);
    }

    if (hotelFilterData.IsActive != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(a => a.IsActive == hotelFilterData.IsActive);
    }

    if (hotelFilterData.StarRating != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(h => h.StarRating == hotelFilterData.StarRating);
    }

    if (hotelFilterData.HotelName != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(h => h.HotelName == hotelFilterData.HotelName.ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hotelFilterData.CreatedDateRange))
    {
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        _filterHelper.GetFilterDates(hotelFilterData.CreatedDateRange, out startDate, out endDate);
        query = query.Where(h => h.CreatedDate >= startDate.ToUniversalTime() && h.CreatedDate <= endDate.ToUniversalTime());
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hotelFilterData.ModifiedDateRange))
    {
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        _filterHelper.GetFilterDates(hotelFilterData.ModifiedDateRange, out startDate, out endDate);
        query = query.Where(h => h.ModifiedDate >= startDate.ToUniversalTime() && h.ModifiedDate <= endDate.ToUniversalTime());
    }

    var sortFields = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<HotelEntity, object>>>
    {
        { "id", h => h.Id },
        { "brandid", h => h.BrandId },
        { "hotelname", h => h.HotelName },
        { "starrating", h => h.StarRating },
        { "isactive", h => h.IsActive! },
        { "createddate", h => h.CreatedDate },
        { "modifieddate", h => h.ModifiedDate }
    };

    query = query.Sort(sortFields, sortField, sortOrder);

    int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

    query = query.Paginate(pageNumber, pageSize);

    List<Hotel> hotelsList = await query.GetHotelData().ToListAsync();

    return hotelsList.GetResultDataList(totalCount, pageNumber, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder);
}
```

Only the relevant data is selected through the following method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Core.Models.Hotel> GetHotelData(this IQueryable<Infrastructure.Data.Entities.Hotel> query)
{
    return query.Include(h => h.HotelAmenities)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.Amenity)
                .Include(h => h.HotelFacilities)
                .Include(h => h.HotelRestaurants)
                .Include(h => h.HotelActivities)
                .Include(h => h.HotelGalleries)
                .Include(h => h.HotelVideos)
                .Include(h => h.HotelRooms)
                .ThenInclude(r => r.HotelRoomFacilities)
                .Select(h => new Core.Models.Hotel().MapToCoreHotelModel(h));
}
```

```cs
public static Core.Models.Hotel MapToCoreHotelModel(this Core.Models.Hotel hotel, Data.Entities.Hotel existingHotel)
{
    hotel.Id = existingHotel.Id;
    hotel.HotelName = existingHotel.HotelName;
    hotel.Description = existingHotel.Description;
    hotel.StarRating = existingHotel.StarRating;
    hotel.BrandId = existingHotel.BrandId;
    hotel.CheckInTime = existingHotel.CheckInTime.HasValue ? existingHotel.CheckInTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") : null;
    hotel.CheckOutTime = existingHotel.CheckOutTime.HasValue ? existingHotel.CheckOutTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") : null;
    hotel.TripAdvisorInfo = new TripAdvisorInfo()
    {
        TripAdvisorId = existingHotel.TripAdvisorId
    };
    hotel.HotelAmenities = existingHotel.HotelAmenities.Select(a => new BasicAmenityData()
    {
        Id = a.AmenityId,
        Name = a.Amenity.Name,
        IconUrl = a.Amenity.IconUrl,
        IconAltText = a.Amenity.IconAltText
    }).ToList();
    hotel.HotelFacilities = existingHotel.HotelFacilities.Select(f => new DescriptionData()
    {
        Id = f.Id,
        Description = f.Description
    }).ToList();
    hotel.HotelRestaurants = existingHotel.HotelRestaurants.Select(f => new DescriptionData()
    {
        Id = f.Id,
        Description = f.Description
    }).ToList();
    hotel.HotelActivities = existingHotel.HotelActivities.Select(f => new DescriptionData()
    {
        Id = f.Id,
        Description = f.Description
    }).ToList();
    hotel.HotelGalleries = existingHotel.HotelGalleries.Select(g => new Gallery()
    {
        Id = g.Id,
        ImageUrl = g.ImageUrl,
        ImageAltText = g.ImageAltText
    }).ToList();
    hotel.Video = existingHotel.HotelVideos.Select(v => new Video()
    {
        Id = v.Id,
        Title = v.Title,
        Subtitle = v.Subtitle,
        Description = v.Description,
        ImageUrl = v.ThumbnailImageUrl,
        ImageAltText = v.ThumbnailImageAltText,
        VideoUrl = v.VideoUrl
    }).FirstOrDefault()!;
    hotel.HotelRooms = existingHotel.HotelRooms.Select(r => new Core.Models.HotelRoom()
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Title = r.Title,
        Description = r.Description,
        ImageUrl = r.ImageUrl,
        ImageAltText = r.ImageAltText,
        HotelRoomFacilities = r.HotelRoomFacilities.Select(rf => new DescriptionData()
        {
            Id = rf.Id,
            Description = rf.Description
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
    hotel.IsActive = existingHotel.IsActive;
    hotel.CreatedDate = existingHotel.CreatedDate;
    hotel.ModifiedDate = existingHotel.ModifiedDate;

    return hotel;
}
```

Following is a sample of the query generated through Entity Framework:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.brand_id, t.check_in_time, t.check_out_time, t.created_date, t.description, t.hotel_name, t.is_active, t.modified_date, t.star_rating, t.trip_advisor_id, t0.hotel_id, t0.amenity_id, 
t0.created_date, t0.modified_date, t0.id, t0.amenity_type_id, t0.brand_id, t0.created_date0, t0.icon_alt_text, t0.icon_image_key_id, t0.icon_url, t0.is_active, t0.modified_date0, t0.name, h1.id, 
h1.created_date, h1.description, h1.hotel_id, h1.modified_date, h2.id, h2.created_date, h2.description, h2.hotel_id, h2.modified_date, h3.id, h3.created_date, h3.description, h3.hotel_id, 
h3.modified_date, h4.id, h4.created_date, h4.hotel_id, h4.image_alt_text, h4.image_key_id, h4.image_url, h4.modified_date, h5.id, h5.created_date, h5.description, h5.hotel_id, h5.modified_date, 
h5.subtitle, h5.thumbnail_image_alt_text, h5.thumbnail_image_key_id, h5.thumbnail_image_url, h5.title, h5.video_url, t1.id, t1.created_date, t1.description, t1.hotel_id, t1.image_alt_text, 
t1.image_key_id, t1.image_url, t1.modified_date, t1.title, t1.id0, t1.created_date0, t1.description0, t1.hotel_room_id, t1.modified_date0
FROM (
   SELECT h.id, h.brand_id, h.check_in_time, h.check_out_time, h.created_date, h.description, h.hotel_name, h.is_active, h.modified_date, h.star_rating, h.trip_advisor_id
   FROM hotel AS h
   ORDER BY h.created_date DESC
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT h0.hotel_id, h0.amenity_id, h0.created_date, h0.modified_date, a.id, a.amenity_type_id, a.brand_id, a.created_date AS created_date0, a.icon_alt_text, a.icon_image_key_id, a.icon_url, 
    a.is_active, a.modified_date AS modified_date0, a.name
    FROM hotel_amenity AS h0
    INNER JOIN amenity AS a ON h0.amenity_id = a.id
    ) AS t0 ON t.id = t0.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN hotel_facility AS h1 ON t.id = h1.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN hotel_restaurant AS h2 ON t.id = h2.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN hotel_activity AS h3 ON t.id = h3.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN hotel_gallery AS h4 ON t.id = h4.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN hotel_video AS h5 ON t.id = h5.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT h6.id, h6.created_date, h6.description, h6.hotel_id, h6.image_alt_text, h6.image_key_id, h6.image_url, h6.modified_date, h6.title, h7.id AS id0, h7.created_date AS created_date0, 
    h7.description AS description0, h7.hotel_room_id, h7.modified_date AS modified_date0
    FROM hotel_room AS h6
    LEFT JOIN hotel_room_facility AS h7 ON h6.id = h7.hotel_room_id
    ) AS t1 ON t.id = t1.hotel_id
ORDER BY t.created_date DESC, t.id, t0.hotel_id, t0.amenity_id, t0.id, h1.id, h2.id, h3.id, h4.id, h5.id, t1.id
```

Following are the database table structures and their non-clustered indexes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel (
    id SERIAL,
    hotel_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    star_rating INT NOT NULL,
    trip_advisor_id INT NOT NULL,
    check_in_time time,
    check_out_time time,
    brand_id INT NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_brandId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand(mos_brand_id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_name_unique UNIQUE(hotel_name),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_name_uppercasecheck CHECK(UPPER(name) = name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_facility (
    id SERIAL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_facility_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_facility_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_restaurant (
    id SERIAL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_restaurant_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_restaurant_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_activity (
    id SERIAL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_activity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_activity_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_gallery (
    id SERIAL,
    image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_gallery_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_gallery_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_video (
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    subtitle VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    thumbnail_image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    thumbnail_image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    thumbnail_image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    video_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    video_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_video_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_video_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_amenity (
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    amenity_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_amenity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (hotel_id, amenity_id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_amenity_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_amenity_amenityId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (amenity_id) REFERENCES amenity(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_room (
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    hotel_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_room_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_room_hotelId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES hotel(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel_room_facility (
    id SERIAL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    hotel_room_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT hotel_room_facility_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT hotel_room_facility_hotelRoomId_fkey FOREIGN KEY (hotel_room_id) REFERENCES hotel_room(id)
);
```

- Verified that we have already added non-clustered indexes to the foreign key columns involved in the table joins.
- We broke down one of the composite indexes to several single indexes.
- Since the query execution plan points to higher costs in ordering data, we tried adding new non-clustered indexes to fields which can be used in the application to sort data.

None of the above made any significant difference in the result.

Comment: 8 `left join`s? do you need them all? is this for reporting or is it for something for interactive display? there are times when lazy loading is acceptable..

Comment: Probably [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#cartesian-explosion). But also, don't `Include` everything and pick what you need afterwards. Do the projection (i.e. the code in `MapToCoreHotelModel`) directly, and EF will figure out which columns need to be queried. Or use AutoMapper.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this SQL statement? (in plain text, as an update of the question)

Comment: By the way, to me it looks like many foreign keys point into the wrong direction. A hotel_facility "pool" is not something unique for a single hotel. Same issue with hotel_activity and hotel_room_facility

Comment: You apparently have looked at a plan, but you haven't shown one to us.  That severely limits what we can tell you.

Comment: If the timeout causes more problems than it solves, why have it?  You should disable it, either it globally or in one session you use for testing so that you can capture an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: There was not enough space to include the results of `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)`, so I am providing you with this link: https://travelcenter1-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/dinusha_moresandtechnologies_com/Ef14ncXU3f1Oigg8hajAxg4BxOMRvAs-1M58cC7v9qSn6g?e=eZ1Mi0.